# How to append some letters or numbers to already existing data

Tags: mysql

I would like to append some data to already existing data, something like 
`720967537` to `255720967537`. All the data in my column is in that format. Is there any way I can do that to all of the records that are in my MySQL database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function:

```
select concat(255, 720967537), concat('my ', 'test')
```

Results:

```
255720967537, my test
```

[SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19f9d/3)

If you want to UPDATE the values in your table, you could do the following:

```
update t
set col1 = concat(255, col1)
  , col2 = concat('my ', col2);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8fe13/1)

Comment: Thank you @bluefeet how do i make that iterate through my whole column

Comment: are you concatenating the same value to each row? If so then you will just apply the concat() on the table, similar to the SQL Fiddle